# Does XBMC supports hardware decoding on Rikomagic MK802 III running Android 4.1.1

Tags: android, kodi, arm

I am looking foward to buy a Rikomagic MK802 IIIs mini-pc to be used as a media center. I expect it to run any type of video, including HD and Full-HD videos.

Since I'm looking foward to use XBMC as the main player, I was wondering if XBMC fully supports hardware decoding in the MK802 IIIs.

I believe that without hardware decoding, the CPU based decoding on the ARM may not be enough to play HD and Full-HD content.

So, is there any XBMC build that runs hardware decoding on the MK802 IIIs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No xbmc does not at this time support hardware decoding on the mk802 III however it is possible to configure xbmc to use another player which does support hardware decoding as discussed here:

[XBMC Wiki - External Players](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=External_players)

This is a playercorefactory.xml which lists a few common players:

[playercorefactory.xml](https://nuskunetworks.box.com/s/wzzbunuqew9rh3ospczj)

Comment: does this other player support subtitles and other XBMC functions?